# PostgreSQL DROP TABLE query freezes

Tags: python, postgresql, wxpython, psycopg2

I am writing code to create a GUI in Python on the Spyder environment of Anaconda. within this code I operate with a PostgreSQL database and I therefore use the psycopg2 database adapter so that I can interact with directly from the GUI.

The code is too long to post here, as it is over 3000 lines, but to summarize, I have no problem interacting with my database except when I try to drop a table.

When I do so, the GUI frames become unresponsive, the `drop table` query doesn't drop the intended table and no errors or anything else of that kind are thrown.

Within my code, all operations which result in a table being dropped are processed via a function (`DeleteTable`). When I call this function, there are no problems as I have inserted several print statements previously which confirmed that everything was in order. The problem occurs when I execute the statement with the `cur.execute(sql)` line of code.

Can anybody figure out why my tables won't drop?

```
def DeleteTable(table_name):

    conn=psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='trial2' user='postgres'   password='postgres'")
    cur=conn.cursor()
    sql="""DROP TABLE """+table_name+""";"""
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Use `try-except` to catch the error. Also simplify your query you don't need so many quotations. Use this: `sql = "DROP TABLE %s;" % table_name`

Comment: I tried and nothing changed, no errors and still freezes

Comment: You probably need to `commit` after each `execute` (as appropriate) or use `autocommit` when connecting. See: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/transaction/

Comment: thanks, I managed to get around it by doing the following: sql="""SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
        FROM pg_stat_activity 
        WHERE datname='trial2'
        AND state = 'idle in transaction'"""

Comment: I restarted my vs code, checked `\d` only to find that the selected tables for deletion no longer exist

Answer (score 11):

That must be because a concurrent transaction is holding a lock that blocks the `DROP TABLE` statement.

Examine the `pg_stat_activity` view and watch out for sessions with `state` equal to `idle in transaction` or `active` that have an `xact_start` of more than a few seconds ago.

This is essentially an application bug: you must make sure that all transactions are closed immediately, otherwise Bad Things can happen.

Comment: what is the command to do this? also what would be the best way to make sure all transactions are closed properly?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state IN ('active', 'idle in transaction') AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();` - The only way to make sure that transactions are closed is to close them, sorry. You can set the `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` as a stop-gap measure against a buggy application.

Comment: when I run and print the result of the code I get a lot of transactions, how do I close them all and also how would I implement the 'idle_in_transaction_session_timeout ' stop-gap measure?

Comment: idle_in_transaction_session_timeout is a configuration parameter that you (usually) set in postgresql.conf.  To prevent leaving behind connections that are idle in transaction, either commit or rollback after executing a query or set the connection to autocommit mode.

Comment: Either restart the PostgreSQL database server or use the `pg_terminate_backend()` function on each `pid`.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue when using psycopg2 within airflow's postgres hook and I resolved it with `with statement`. Probably this resolves the issue because the connection becomes local within the `with statement`.

```
def drop_table():
    with PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="your_connection").get_conn() as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS your_table")

task_drop_table = PythonOperator(
    task_id="drop_table",
    python_callable=drop_table
)
```

And a solution is possible for the original code above like this (I didn't test this one):

```
def DeleteTable(table_name):

    with psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='trial2' user='postgres'   password='postgres'") as conn:
        cur=conn.cursor()
        sql="""DROP TABLE """+table_name+""";"""
        cur.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
```

Please comment if anyone tries this.

Comment: Hi @matlihan. Can you explain why your code resolves dropping tables in contrast to the original code?

Comment: Sure, and sorry I thought psycopg2 is used within airflow postgres operator. I will edit it with explanation.